# How to configure an appender with CUSTOM MARKER or (WARN or ERROR)?

Tags: log4j2

I would like to configure an appender to use custom marker or WARN, ERROR and above level logs. So that it would contain logs with custom marker or error, warning etc. Can I do it without creating additional marker for WARN and ERROR? Here is my config:

```
<Filters>
    <MarkerFilter marker="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
    <MarkerFilter marker="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
    <MarkerFilter marker="successfulRequestMarker" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
</Filters>
```

But errors and warns are not logged. I set level to INFO in AppenderRef for this appender.

PS: I am using log4j2 version 2.5 with slf4j 1.7.12 for the marker
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow logs with levels WARN and above or your custom marker you would do:

```
<Filters>
    <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
    <MarkerFilter marker="successfulRequestMarker" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
</Filters>
```